# Public and Private visibility proper usage

Tags: c#

I am ending up with all my function access modifiers as public. Is it wrong to have all functions as public or they should be private as well. I have a layered application where one layer calls public functions of another layer. I have few private functions.

Comment: Are you in some competition about "*my* number of private functions is bigger than yours"? If all functions need to called outside of the class (and functions are appropriately sized) than you don't really need private functions.

Comment: Thanks. I just had to confirm.

Comment: Restrict everything, then expand the visibility where needed. There's nothing more we can tell you.

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb is that everything that you do not need to be visible to the outside (implementation details and functions) should be `private`.

If you declare everything as public then I cannot say that you are making a catastrophic mistake, the world won't tear apart, it's just that the purists will always find some motives to critique you and you will have uncalm consciousnesses. You might wake up at night thinking that you made a terrible mistake by not making those methods private because nobody outside of the current class is calling them. You could also be on the other side of course: sleeping well at night while some other developer is cursing at you for not making this method public as he cannot call it directly.

So it's up to you to decide on which side you want to be.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this answer is, if your layered application is all within the same assembly, consider using [Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) instead of public.